# react-native-image-to-pdf gives atempt to invoke virtual method error

Tags: javascript, react-native

Whether I use react-native-image-to-pdf or react-native-pdf-lib to create a pdf in my react-native app, I get the error:

> [Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference].

I am using react-native-image-crop-picker to pick multiple images.
I am building this app for Android.
Here is my code:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';
    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
    import RNImageToPdf from 'react-native-image-to-pdf';

    const App = () => {
    var photoPath = [];
    const handlePick = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
    multiple: true,
   })
  .then((image) => {
    console.log(image.path);
    photoPath.push(image.path);
   })
  .then(async () => {
    try {
      const options = {
        imagePaths: photoPath,
        name: 'PDFName',
        maxSize: {
     // optional maximum image dimension - larger images will be resized
          width: 900,
          height: Math.round((deviceHeight() / deviceWidth()) * 900),
        },
        quality: 0.7, // optional compression paramter
      };
      const pdf = await RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages(options);

      console.log(pdf.filePath);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
 };

     return (
      <View>
       <Button title="Pick image" onPress={handlePick} />
      </View>
    );
  };

   export default App;
```